# Defining new Dictionary members methods C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, methods, return, keyvaluepair

I want to define a new member method for Dictionary as it already built in member methods e.g. `Add()`, `Clear()`, `ContainsKey()` etc.

That newly added member method should return all the keyvaluepairs in form of a Set as we can return map.entrySet() to Set in Java.

Can existing methods for dictionary be overridden to achieve this ?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want it? What are you doing that getting a map.entrySet() equivalent will help you solve that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an extension method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public static class DictionaryExtensions {
    public static HashSet<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> ToSet<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict) {
        return new HashSet<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>(dict.ToList());
    }
}
```

Info about extension methods: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: where we have to declare this class and method?

Comment: Check the link added to the answer. You may add this class to any project where you need to use ToSet()

Comment: do we need to declare as DictionaryExtension<T> {...} as To use KVP<T,T> inside ?

Comment: It's a static class, there is no need to create a generic one. Please read more about what extension methods are and how to use them inside the link I provided. It's truly a board topic.

Comment: But when I declared it inside my class, it gives error due to `KVP<TKey, TValue>` as type or namespace couldn't be found

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand your problem. You have to create a new class in a new file and add the correct using statements to it (e.g. System.Collections.Generics).

Comment: You may choose the name you like, but the class must be static.

Comment: I have declared as:  
`public static class MyExtensions
    {
       public static HashSet<KeyValuePair<T, T>> ToSet(this Dictionary<T, T> _dict)
       {
            return new HashSet<KeyValuePair<T, T>>(_dict.ToList());
       }
    }`  
But still type or namespace couldn't be found error

Comment: Just by adding `MyExtensions<T>` then no error, why is it so?

Comment: Comments are not a chat, please never create extended discussion here. By the way, is not <T, T>, but <TKey, TValue>.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113815/discussion-between-taufel-and-federico-dipuma).

Comment: Please check again the answer, I've updated it. It should work out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware it's not a set, but by using Linq you can get a list of key value pairs like so:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> keyValuePairs = dictionary.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it helps, you can access KeyValue pair of the Dictionary like this  :

```
// Example dictionary
var dic = new Dictionary<int, string>{{1, "a"}};

foreach (var item in dic)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("key : {0}, Value : {1}", item.Key, item.Value));
}
```

Comment: I want to have a method which return all KeyValuePair of the Dictionary which I can call as an extension method